# Trying to generate a word document in a .NET Windows Service

Tags: .net, interop

In a Windows Service I'm trying to convert a document from word to pdf.

The code used is pretty simple:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate a PDF document from a Word document.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputFile">Path to the input Word document</param>
/// <param name="outputFile">Path to the output PDF document</param>
/// <returns>Exception string in case of error. Empty string if ok.</returns>
private string DocToPDF(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    try
    {
        object inputfileName = inputFile;
        object outputfileName = outputFile;
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;
        object lockComments = false;
        object passWord = Missing.Value;
        object addToRecentFiles = false;
        object writePassword = Missing.Value;
        object readOnlyRecommended = false;
        object embedTruetypeFonts = false;
        object saveNativePictureFormat = true;
        object saveFormsData = false;
        object saveAsAOCELetter = false;
        object newTemplate = false;
        object docType = WdNewDocumentType.wdNewBlankDocument; //Missing.Value;
        object beVisisble = true;

        MWordApp.Visible = MWordVisible;
        Document wordDoc = MWordApp.Documents.Add(ref inputfileName, ref newTemplate, ref 
                                                  docType, ref beVisisble);
        wordDoc.SaveAs(ref outputfileName, ref fileFormat, ref lockComments, ref passWord, ref 
                       addToRecentFiles,
                       ref writePassword, ref readOnlyRecommended, ref embedTruetypeFonts, ref     
                       saveNativePictureFormat,
                       ref saveFormsData, ref saveAsAOCELetter);
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

When the code is triggered I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A13E9): Word has encountered a problem.
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents.Add(Object& Template, Object& NewTemplate, Object& DocumentType, Object& Visible)
> at DocService.Listener.DocToPDF(String inputFile, String outputFile) in E:\Projects\DocService\DocService\DocService.cs:line 77

I looked up the error and found a couple of work arounds (like placing a folder "Desktop" in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile") but nothing worked.

Now, the service itself is pretty ancient. The service was originally written to run on 32-bit Windows with Office 2010 32 bit.

I'm currently trying to run it on 64-bit Windows Server 2016 with Office 365 64-bit

I'll be trying to rebuild the entire application in 64 bit, to see if that makes a difference. (just realized the problem might be simply the office version being in 64 bit rather than 32 bit)

Does anybody here have any idea what else it might be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be caused by the user the service was running on. Needed to use an interactive user, and I got past the error.